# How To Add An RSS Feed To My Search.php file?

Tags: php

I'm running a social network and right now my search.php shows results for people, and tags. How can I add an RSS Feed? I own a blog and I wanted to add my RSS Feed to the search so whenever someone searches for a topic it will show up on the search page.

Here's the search.php code:

```
$feed = new feed();
$feed->db = $db;
$feed->url = $CONF['url'];

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']) || isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {    
    $verify = $loggedIn->verify();

    if($verify['username']) {
        $feed->user = $verify;
        $feed->username = $verify['username'];
        $feed->id = $verify['idu'];

        if(isset($_GET['tag'])) {
            $skin = new skin('shared/top'); $top = '';

            $TMPL['theme_url'] = $CONF['theme_url'];
            $TMPL['private_message'] = $verify['privacy'];
            $TMPL['avatar'] = $verify['image'];
            $TMPL['url'] = $CONF['url'];

            $top = $skin->make();
        }
    }
}

$feed->per_page = $settings['perpage'];
$feed->time = $settings['time'];
$feed->censor = $settings['censor'];
$feed->smiles = $settings['smiles'];
$feed->c_per_page = $settings['cperpage'];
$feed->c_start = 0;
$feed->l_per_post = $settings['lperpost'];

$TMPL_old = $TMPL; $TMPL = array();
$skin = new skin('shared/rows'); $rows = '';

if(empty($_GET['filter'])) {
    $_GET['filter'] = '';
}

// Allowed types
if(isset($_GET['tag'])) {
    // If the $_GET keyword is empty [hashtag]
    if($_GET['tag'] == '') {
        header("Location: ".$CONF['url']."/index.php?a=welcome");
    }
    $hashtags = $feed->getHashtags(0, $settings['qperpage'], $_GET['tag'], null);
    $TMPL['messages'] = $hashtags[0];
} else {
    // If the $_GET keyword is empty [user]
    if($_GET['q'] == '') {
        header("Location: ".$CONF['url']."/index.php?a=welcome");
    }
    $TMPL['messages'] = $feed->getSearch(0, $settings['qperpage'], $_GET['q'], $_GET['filter']);
}
$rows = $skin->make();

$skin = new skin('search/sidebar'); $sidebar = '';

if(isset($_GET['tag'])) {
    $TMPL['trending'] = $feed->sidebarTrending($_GET['tag'], 10);
} else {
    $TMPL['genre'] = $feed->sidebarGender($_GET['filter'], $_GET['q']);
}
$TMPL['ad'] = generateAd($settings['ad6']);

$sidebar = $skin->make();

$TMPL = $TMPL_old; unset($TMPL_old);
$TMPL['top'] = $top;
$TMPL['rows'] = $rows;
$TMPL['sidebar'] = $sidebar;

if(isset($_GET['logout']) == 1) {
    $loggedIn->logOut();
    header("Location: ".$CONF['url']."/index.php?a=welcome");
}

$TMPL['url'] = $CONF['url'];

if(isset($_GET['tag'])) {
    $TMPL['title'] = '#'.$_GET['tag'].' - '.$settings['title'];
} else {
    $TMPL['title'] = $LNG['title_search'].' - '.$_GET['q'].' - '.$settings['title'];
}

$skin = new skin('shared/timeline_x');
return $skin->make();
```

Please help :)

Comment: There's nothing much to it, it's just a page output in a particular agreed format for other programs to load. The only thing you need to know is the format, and a quick web search will turn up plenty of documentation on that, as well as lots of libraries that simplify generating the right format.

Answer (score -1):

Try this example

```
<?php 

    $articles = $pages->find('blog')->children()->visible()->flip()->limit(10);

    snippet('feed', array(
      'link'  => url('blog'),
      'items' => $articles,
      'descriptionField'  => 'text', 
      'descriptionLength' => 300
    ));

    ?>
```

link:
This is the main link in our feed, which takes the visitor back to our site. In this case we want them to get back to our blog, so we build an url to our blog with the url() helper function.

items:
As items for our feed, we pass the set of $articles we found in the first line. The feed snippet will automatically take care of getting the right info out of those $articles (like title, url, etc.)

descriptionField:
If you want to show a description for each item in your feed, you need to specify a field, which is available in any item and should be used for the description.

descriptionLength:
This is maximum number of characters the description will have. An excerpt is automatically generated by the feed snippet.

Comment: What is `snippet`? What is this crazy `$pages` object? Have you taken this out of context from the middle of a tutorial by any chance? Because there's no actual code to do anything here.

Comment: Ah, [yes, you did](http://getkirby.com/blog/how-to-add-a-rss-feed). And it's a tutorial for building RSS with a particular CMS, so pretty useless to the OP.

Comment: This code won't help me, I'm still learning PHP but I know enough to display certain things such as people, and tags.. I just need to figure out how I can add my RSS Feed from my blog and make it display in searches, I'm trying my best to implement it myself